# Recursive function using rbind() results in error "Item 2 has 3 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 2 columns"

Tags: r, recursion, data.table

I have a data.table of employees with an EmployeeID column and a ManagerID column (which is a foreign key to the EmployeeID column of the same table).  I'm trying to write a function to return a table of all the subordinates for a set of managers (not just direct subordinates, but subordinates' subordinates and so on).

Here's what I tried:

```
getSubordinates <- function(mgrs){

  mgrs[, ManagerID:=NULL]
  setnames(mgrs, "EmployeeID", "ManagerID")
  setkey(mgrs, "ManagerID")
  setkey(emps, "ManagerID")
  directReports <- emps[mgrs[, list(ManagerID)], nomatch=0]
  print(directReports[0])

  if(nrow(directReports)==0){
    return(directReports[0]) # Return an empty table with all the columns of directReports
  } else{
    return(rbind(directReports, getSubordinates(directReports)))
  }
}

emps <- data.table(EmployeeName=c("Bob", "John", "Sue", "Carl"), EmployeeID=c(1,2,3,4), ManagerID=c(NA,1,1,2))
emps
   EmployeeName EmployeeID ManagerID
1:          Bob          1        NA
2:         John          2         1
3:          Sue          3         1
4:         Carl          4         2
```

However, when I run

```
getSubordinates(emps[EmployeeID==1])
```

I get the error:

> Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill) : 
>     Item 2 has 3 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 2 columns. If instead you need to fill missing columns, use set argument 'fill' to TRUE.

I understand what the error means, but can't figure out why I'm getting it.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, I'm using R 3.1.2 and data.table 1.9.4 and unable to upgrade. (I'm at the mercy of my company's IT department.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you modify the `data.table` in the function call, you have to make a `copy()` of it:

```
library(data.table)
getSubordinates <- function(mgrs){
        mgrs[, ManagerID:=NULL]
        setnames(mgrs, "EmployeeID", "ManagerID")
        setkey(mgrs, "ManagerID")
        setkey(emps, "ManagerID")
        directReports <- emps[mgrs[, list(ManagerID)], nomatch=0]

        if(nrow(directReports)==0){
                return(directReports) # Return an empty table with all the columns of directReports
        } else{
                return(rbind( directReports, getSubordinates(copy(directReports))))
        }
}
getSubordinates(emps[EmployeeID==1])
   EmployeeName EmployeeID ManagerID
1:         John          2         1
2:          Sue          3         1
3:         Carl          4         2
```